# Excel Addin : Workbook refresh with data mode , Error : The cartridge directory could not be found

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, powerpivot

I had a 2013 32-bit excel (Professional edition) and I am developing an addin. In  this addin I refresh a excel workbook. This workbook has a Data Model. My OS was recently upgraded from Windows 8 to Windows 10.

When I was refreshing the workbook through code, it throws me an error :

"We couldn't get data from the Data Model."

**The cartridge directory could not be found.  Use the Windows Installer to repair the application.  Exception of type 'Microsoft.Office.PowerPivot.BackEnd.StorageException' was thrown."**

I saw this  [link in MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bc4a2008-3a30-4454-91fa-9455ad232e9f/the-cartridge-directory-could-not-be-found?forum=exceldev) forums and tried to install 32 bit of those Hotifixes mentioned in the link, but it said "The hotfix was already installed".

I thought that may be something got corrupt while upgrade from Windows 8 to Windows 10. So I uninstalled 32-bit of office and restarted machine. Then I installed the Office 64-bit Professional version.

I then again tried to install the 64 bit version of the hotfixes but again got message "There is no software to apply this hotfix".I tried to run the add in code again but it again threw the same error again. My 64-bit machine is a click and run version of office (I checked in registry based on a article).

I do not think for my new 64 bit office, no updates are applied. I am not sure what is causing the error. Please advise.

My question are:

1. Any suggestion what could be happening
2. In Click and Run version of office 2013 , how do I update (All updates available) that ? I do not see any way I can update.
3. Is this issue resolved in any SP or CU.
4. Any way to resolve this?

I am currently stuck with this. Note : It works when manually refreshing. Just throws error when doing this through C# code.

- Girija